# Unzip file to named pipe and file

Tags: bash, tee

I'm trying to unzip a file and redirect the output to a named pipe and another file. Therefore I'm using the command `tee`.

`gunzip -c $FILE | tee -a $UNZIPPED_FILE > $PIPE`

My question is is there any other option to achieve the same but with a command that will write the file asynchronously. I want the output redirected to the pipe immediately and that the writing to the file will run in the background by teeing the output to some sort of buffer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you already have "some sort of buffer"

Comment: Sorry that I may have expressed my problem in a complicated way. I'm trying to decouple the file writing from `tee` so that the output of `gunzip` will be redirected directly to $PIPE. Therefore I came up with the idea of a buffer that allows this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a named pipe (FIFO). First create one:

```
mkfifo fifo
```

Now we need a process reading from the named pipe. There's an old unix utillity called `buffer` that was earlier for asynchronous writing to tape devices. Start a process reading from the pipe in the background:

```
buffer -i fifo -o async_file -u 100000 -t &
```

`-i` is the input file and `-o` the output file. The `-u` flag is only for you to see, that it is really asynchonous. It's a small pause after every write for 1/10 second. And `-t` gives a summary when finished.

Now start the `gunzip` process:

```
gunzip -c archive.gz | tee -a fifo > $OTHER_PIPE
```

You see the gunzip process is ending very fast. In the folder you will see the file `async_file` growing slowly, that's the background process that is writig to that file, the `buffer` process. When finishing (can take very long with a huge file) you see a summary. The other file is written directly.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. As I understand your solution the output will be buffered before the tee command. I only want to buffer the output for the file not for writing it to the pipe.

Comment: No I'm looking for a way to unzip a file and redirect the output to file on disk and to a named pipe. The problem is that the disk I/O is way too slow and I want to write the output to the disk asynchronously and write to the pipe directly.

Comment: @what I misunderstood you question sorry. Now it should be correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only problem I still have that I do not have the rights to install buffer. Will it make any differences using `cat fifo > aysnc_file &` ?

Comment: I think there is one problem left. The tee command will not write to $OTHER_PIPE as long nobody reads from fifo and therefore I think there is no performance improvement. I tried the same with a little example: `echo "hello" | tee fifo`. Hello will only be printed to the console if someone read from the pipe.

Comment: I don't see a way around that. Maybe you could try it with `dd`, but definitely not with `cat`. `buffer` loads everything into shared memory and that's why `buffer` is not blocking compared to `cat`.

Comment: Sorry I have to ask but you do not see a way around what? Using `buffer`or that tee will only redirect to stdout when someone read from the pipe.

Comment: @aQuip using `buffer`. Or another nonblocking buffering utillity.